# How to call multiple partials in parent view in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call multiple partials in parent view. I have tried multiple way but could not succeed. I think there is something missing in View. Please guide me where i am going wrong.

Note: I have partials in the question. Please suggest me.

The following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type 'Aplication.Models.ABC.ClsA', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Aplication.Models.ABC.first]'.'

Model

```
public class ClsA
{        
    public List<first> firsts{ get; set; }    
    public List<second> seconds{ get; set; }
}

public class first
{     
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}

public class second
{
    public string Details{ get; set; }
    public string Age{ get; set; }             
}
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult ABC()
    {
        SDetails sDetails=new SDetails();        
        var model = new ClsA();
        model.firsts = sDetails.Rst();            
        model.seconds = sDetails.Rs();           
        return View(model);
    }
```

View

```
 @model Aplication.Models.ABC.ClsA 

  @Html.Partial("_PartialA");           
  @Html.Partial("_PartialB.cshtml")
```

_PartialA

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.first>

    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Address)</th>            
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>                   
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)                    
                </td>                

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

_PartialB

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.second>

    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Details)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Age)</th>            
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Details)
                </td>
                <td>                   
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)                    
                </td>                

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: What are you partial views? And what problem are you having?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have updated partials with the error. Please guide me.

Comment: See the answer by Tjaart van der Walt, The alternative is to make the model in your partials `@model Aplication.Models.ABC.ClsA` and use `@foreach (var item in Model.firsts)` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke, If I pass `Model.firsts` it gives me error `Cannot implicitly convert type void to object`

Comment: That is not possible based on the code you have shown

Comment: You would get that error if you actually used `@Html.RenderPartial(...)` (instead of the correct usage which is `@{ Html.RenderPartial(...); }`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@Html.Partial()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial(v=vs.118).aspx) Takes a second parameter `model`. If you do not pass the parameter to `@Html.Partial()` it will automatically pass the model of the current view.

> Parameters
>
> **htmlHelper**
>   Type: System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper
>   The HTML helper instance that this method extends.
>
> **partialViewName**
>   Type: System.String
>   The name of the partial view to render.
>
> **model**
>   Type: System.Object
>   The model for the partial view.

You need to update your code from

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialA");           
@Html.Partial("_PartialB");
```

To

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialA", Model.firsts);           
@Html.Partial("_PartialB", Model.seconds)
```

You do not need to pass the file extension to the `@Html.Partial` method

Comment: If I pass `Model.firsts` it gives me error `cannot implicitly convert type void to object`

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the line of code where the error is and debug it from there?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of loading partial view. The controller has an action to load the data in a partial view.

```
public ActionResult List()
        {

            var movies = db.Movies;


            return PartialView("_list", movies.ToList());

        }
```

In the partial _list view, you can have something like -

```
 @model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Movie>


 <div class="row">
    <table class="table  table-bordered table-hover" id="moviesTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
                </th>

                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title) 

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete-row" data-item="@item.ID"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.ID } )" class="btn btn-info"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit </a>

                            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.ID } )" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> View </a>

                            <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteInline", new { id = item.ID } )" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>


                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Now you can render the partial view in the main view like below -

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="replacetarget">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("List", "Movies"); }

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's issue.